# Mercurial - log last month changes

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHG with mercurial and I have to log my changes from last month. It has to be something like this in GIT:

```
git log --since="2015-03-01" -p --author='me' > C:\history_3.log
```

Can you tell me how can I do it (using tortoise gui or terminal)?

Comment: Try: `hg log -r "author(<your name here>) and date(>2015-03-01)" > C:\history_3.log`

Comment: I tried hg log -r "kowalski(John Kowalski) and date(>2015-03-01)" > F:\history_3.log
but it said there is invalid token at 15. And how can I set date range?

Answer (score 16):

You want to make use of mercurial's revsets, a very powerful language to filter the revisions listed:

`hg log -r"author('YOURNAME') and date('>2015-03-01')"`

or alternatively for the last 30 days:

`hg log -r"author('YOURNAME') and date('-30')"`.

See `hg help revsets` and `hg help dates`.

EDIT: Using tortoiseHG, you can use the magnifying glass icon in the toolbar (thanks Kevin)

Comment: Revsets can also be put directly into the TortoiseHG GUI.  Just click the magnifying glass icon in the toolbar.