# Finding logical change log

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to figure out a way to get an oddly-specific set of logs. This is input into a different program, where I'm parsing the logs and doing stuff with them, but ideally it would be great to do as much as possible with the hg commands to minimize my post-processing.

I want all commits marked with "O" and none of the "X" ones:

```
A5 O
   |
   |
   |
A4 O   X B4  X C2
   |\  |     |
   | \ |     |
   |  \|     |
A3 O   O B3  |
   |   |     |
   |   |     |
   |   |     |
A2 O   O B2  X C1
   |   |     |
   |   |     |
   |   |     |
   |   O B1  |
   |  /|     |
   | / |     |
   |/  |     |
A1 X   X B0  X C0
   |
   |
   |
A0 X
```

Given this chart, where A, B, and C are different branches, our users want a log of changes between A2 and A5. The issue is that they also want to know the rest of the history of any branches merged into A.

`hg log -r A2:A5` will return:

- A2,3,4,5
- B2,3,4
- C1,2

First off, I don't want C whatsoever. It isn't connected to anything here.
But what I do want is B1, or more generally all changes in B since it was last merged into A. Also I don't want B4. So if I have hanging tails that connect farther up, I need to find the rest. Annoyingly, they do *not* want A1.

My current plan is log A2:A5, then I create a tree structure from parsing the results. At the end I look for any hanging tails, and get the log of the common ancestor of that tail and A2, and A2, for just that branch. That's sort of convoluted and crazy.

Any ideas or suggestions to make this easy and reduce the work I have to do to post-process?

Comment: Have you ever read "hg help revsets"? I don't have time to construct a revset for what you're looking for but if you're unaware that the feature exists maybe you'll be able to figure it out after reading the docs.

Comment: try to construct a revset where you query the ancestors of A5 and changesets newer than A1 and B0. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841425/mercurial-log-last-month-changes/29847859#29847859 I described a similar problem

Comment: try `hg log -r "A5  % parents(A2)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An improvement on your current approach will be `hg log -r "A5 % parents(A2)"`. This is equivalent to A5 and all its ancestors, less A1 and any of its ancestors, so it returns:

- `A2`,`A3`,`A4`, and `A5`
- `B0`,`B1`,`B2`, and `B3`

Notably, the following will be excluded:

- Any changeset in `C`
- Changesets in `B` that hasn't been merged into A (e.g. `B4`)

There is only one undesired changeset in the resulting revset: `B0`. The criteria for removing that is a little unclear to me (It would probably help to see the ancestors `A0`, `B0` and `C0`, as they will all stem from a common node at some point). I think a clarification of the stop conditions going backwards on branches that merge into A2::A5 is needed before a revset can be constructed.

However, that revset will probably be quite complicated, and it may be easier to postprocess the above revset instead.

**Edit: Some further thoughts**

You may be better off doing multiple different revsets:

1. `hg log -r "A2::A5"` returns the DAG from `A2` to `A5` (i.e. `A2`,`A3`,`A4`,`A5`)
2. `hg log -r "(parents( A2::A5 & merge() ) - ( A2::A5 + parents(A2) ) )"` will return any changeset that has been merged *into* the DAG from `A2` to `A5` (i.e. `B3`)

The first one will go directly to your final result set. The second one you can iterate (Imagine there's also a branch `D` with a `D3` that's merged into the branch of interest) and traverse each branch towards the stop criteria, then add the relevant changesets into the final result set.

Iterating the merged branches to stop at the right time may be simpler than trying to prune a larger result set of the incorrectly included changesets

Comment: THanks for this! I'll play around with this idea. This might be less work to postprocess than my current approach.

Comment: Your edits are even better. I had never thought to combine multiple revset statements in that way.

Comment: I'm glad you like it. I've just realised you'd get `A1` in the second revset if `A2` is a merge. Better change `- A2::A5` to `- (A2::A5+parents(A2))`. I'll edit my answer when I have some more time